# How to integrate swagger and Katharsis?

Tags: java, rest, swagger, katharsis

How to integrate swagger and Katharsis?
I don't know how to put swagger annotation in Katharsis
Katharsis website:  http://katharsis.io/.  Thanks.

```
    @GET
@Path("/{id}")
@RolesAllowed({Roles.SYSTEM_USER})
@ApiOperation(
        value = "Get a XXXXXX."
)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, response = dto.class, message = "Return the xxxxx"))
})
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getXXXXX(
```

Take Jersery as example, we can add some swagger and use swagger-ui to generator a rest document.

How to do this in Katharsis?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Please provide [minimal working example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and more detailed informations.

Comment: thx, and add a Jersey example.

Comment: Even I am looking for this. Also refer: https://github.com/katharsis-project/katharsis-framework/issues/34